# How to differences in properties of three list that are supposed to be the same using LAMBDA

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have a list of objects that in this case are tax forms. `List<TaxForm>();` Now, parts of these forms should have the same information as some of the properties. They all come from the same client. How could i look at all the tax forms in the list and check if any of let's say property "RecordB" are different. If so, I need to flag the discrepancies.  I couldn't think of a way to do this using lambda expressions. So for example, all BRecords on each TaxForm should have the same value for PayerName.

```
var hasConflict = taxForms.Where(tf => tf.PayerName != priorTaxForm).Count > 0;
```

I am trying to think of a way like this if possible. If not, I guess I could iterate the list and compare the current to a prior form, and if different, then there are differences. Just seems bad.  Thanks in advance!

An example of what I am trying to accomplish but in a more stable manner is the following:

```
var forms = jobObject.TaxForms;
string payerName = forms[0].ARecord.PayerName;
bool hasConflict = !forms.TrueForAll(tf => tf.ARecord.PayerName == payerName);
```

I apologize for any typos. Sicker than a dog right now and medicated, working from home...  Blah.

---

Based off of reed's answer, I think this is what would best fit my solution and scenario. Would this not work just fine:

Here is what I ended up doing to the thanks of Reed's answer. It was a little different scenario, but I ended up using the similiar concept to fit the needs of my current logic.

```
forms.TrueForAll(t => forms[0].ARecord.PayerName == t.ARecord.PayerName);
```

Actually visible description of problem:

NOTE* ONLY A FEW PROPERTIES NEED TO BE THE SAME IN ALL FORMS. NOT ALL PROPERTIES. SO CHECK IN LIST IF PROPERTYA, PROPERTYB, OR PROERTYC HAVE A CONFLICT WHEN PROPERTY D,E,F IT DOESN'T MATTER. SO THE FOLOWING FORMS WOULD FLAG AS CONFLICT BECAUSE THEY PAYER NAME SHOULD ALWAYS BE THE SAME. THEY ARE FROM THE SAME COMPANY.

Form
   ID:1099R
   PayerName: Some Credit Union
   SubmitDate: 01/12/2015
Form
   ID:1098
   PayerName: Some Credit UnionForm
   SubmitDate: 01/20/2015
Form
   ID:1099INT
   PayerName: Different Name so flag data
   SubmitDate: 01/5/2015

Comment: There's nothing bad about iterating the list. Sometimes LINQ can overcomplicate a simple loop.

Comment: It would be nice to pull a list of what objects do not match the one judged as the base value. In this situation, all the ones that do not match forms[0]. See, I need to then flag them. For now, I will run this, and if it is flagged that there are conflicts, then I will iterate each form and highlight in red where the form values are different. Would be nicer and cleaner to be able to use that expression though, and pull out the ones that do not match into a new list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Zip` to merge the lists together.

```
var conflicts = taxForm1.Zip(taxForm2, (one, two) => new {One = one, Two = two})
                        .Zip(taxForm3, (ot, three) => new {ot.One, ot.Two, Three = three})
                        .Where(f => f.One.PayerName != f.Two.PayerName || f.One.PayerName != f.Three.PayerName);

var hasConflicts =   (taxForm1.Count != taxForm2.Count) 
                  || (taxForm1.Count != taxForm3.Count)
                  || conflicts.Any();
```

---

Edit in response to comment:

If you're just checking to verify that all items in the list are the same, you can do:

```
// Note- requires at least one item in the list.  Add checks if needed.
var hasConflicts = taxForm.Skip(1).Any(t => t.PayerName != taxForm[0].PayerName);
```

Comment: For reference, this is only available in `.NET 4.0` onward.

Comment: They are not multiple list, but a single list. All ARecords for each taxform in the list, should have the same value. For example, the same tax year.

Comment: @Casey Wasn't clear from your question - Just edited to include option for that, too.

Comment: Yea, that was my fault. I tend to try to explain it to quickly, and in doing so, leave out details that DO matter.  lol  Thanks again.